# Validation URL information with nginx

Tags: linux, security, nginx, web, server-administration

We have API application, which uses many customers. Every customer have API token, which he passed in `GET` request.

Example from access log:

```
GET /api/token=FhrHd25Sk6REmwqn32Ssdf/bla?/bla/bla
```

We want to create whitelist for tokens and limit the number of connections per second for each of the tokens using nginx.

Can you advise something on the implementation of this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `limit_req` directive controls the maximum connections per second for various keys (in this case the **key** is the API token). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) for details.

You can extract the API token by using a `map` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $token {
    ~/token=freepass/           '';
    ~/token=(?<thetoken>[^/]+)/ $thetoken;
    default                     'everybody';
}

limit_req_zone $token zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

server {
    ...
    limit_req zone=one;
    ...
}
```

In the above example, the token "freepass" will have unlimited access as it does not define a value for the **key**. The token is extracted using a named capture. The **default** clause places requests with no defined token into the same **key**, which may or may not be what you want, as those requests will be severely limited.

Comment: Thank you!
It looks like a great solution.